# Application name bar disappears after switching to new activity

Tags: java, android, jquery

Basically, the problem is pretty straight-forward if you read the title.

I started my test application for testing purposes and when I'm at the main menu, there is that bar with the application name above and when I click on any button that triggers a new activity, the bar disappears.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uI70f.png

After clicking, in this example, "What's the meaning of life?" button, the result looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mvmY.png

The codes that are used in order to make the button are as follows:

options_menu.xml

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="What is the meaning of life?"
    android:onClick="ShowLifeMeaning"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Life.java

```
public class Life extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.meaning_of_life);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    finish();
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public void ShowLifeMeaning(View view) {

    startActivity(new Intent(this, Life.class));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using

> public class Life extends ActionBarActivity

Comment: The solution regarding the manifest is also an important information regarding the theme

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think it 's because of theme, in your manifest file maybe you right this code for theme :
theme."your theme".NoActionbar or something like this.
if you remove it , it would be correct

Comment: I appreciate your interest, the problem was solved by setting ..extends ActionBarActivity instead of Activity which I had set!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ActionBarActivity.
But this class being deprecated , you can use AppCompatActivity with which you can support actionBar starting from API 7 and it supports fragments as well.

Comment: Thank you a lot, that solved the problem! I started to learn Android Studio and it's very great seeing people help to people who just started.